# Unable to load image when passing it as a prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I trying to create a custom component that accepts an image uri as a property.
When calling this component, I want to pass different uri to this component such that it displays different images.

When i do this, I did not receive any error, but the images did not load(its just blank space there).

I have tried passing the URI directly into the component and the images load properly. However, when I go back to passing the uri as a prop, the image simply won't load

```
export default class CustomComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
}
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <ImageBackground source = {{uri: this.props.imageSource}} style = {{width:100, height:100}}/>
        <View>

    );
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <CustomComponent imageSource ='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/moderncombatgames/images/0/0d/Chicken_Rice.png/revision/latest?cb=20151231093652'/>
);
}
```

I expected the image to load, but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you need the props in the constructor and calling super? If you have constructor() and no super does it work?

Comment: They don't need a constructor as they are not initializing state or binding functions. You need `super(props)` in a constructor otherwise `this.props` will be undefined in the constructor. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor.

Comment: Is this one file?  You cannot have two export defaults in the same file.  Try removing `export default` from both components, and at the bottom, `export { CustomComponent, App }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it appears to work.

I put your CustomComponent into its own file `CustomComponent.js` and imported it into the `App.js`.

Here is a snack with the code working https://snack.expo.io/SJgTkxbQ4

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting 2 classes. Remove the first export default in CustomClass. You only need it internally and you only need to export the App class.

If these are 2 files, please post them completely.

Comment: Yes these are 2 files, sorry about that, didnt know how to post in 2 files. Thanks!